# xamp - local image address redirect to dashboard

Tags: apache, xampp

I've a problem with my xamp , I'm using the latest version of XAMPP Version 7.3.10. 
when I open my url in browser like this "http://192.168.1.105/azmon/Opitures/291382661905330.jpg" it redirect to http://192.168.1.105/dashboard/

the image file is exist and the azmon folder is my project, it runs the php pages without any problem too

how can I fix this ?

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file? Is there a redirect there?

Comment: Any code available?

Comment: Paste you virtual host config

Comment: @JayBlanchard  I've .htaccess but it has nothing to do with the images